# What's involved in an extraction of palatally impacted teeth?

Tags: dentistry

I have two impacted teeth (some combination of premolars and molars) that are on my palate. They are fairly close to my "normal" teeth: generally, the only impact of them on my everyday life is a slight pressure I sometimes feel on the sides of my tongue.

However, my dentist has suggested that I get these teeth extracted, as the gap between them and my "normal" teeth is difficult to clean and they serve no real positive purpose, and if they decay, they may affect the function of my "normal" teeth. I am partly hesitant to agree to this because of memories of painful tooth extractions in my childhood. That's a personal issue, but I also don't know how much such a procedure would involve (and cannot ask my dentist at the moment), and having more knowledge might ease some of the distress about possibly getting the procedure done. Thus:

- Would such an extraction be done in a fashion similar to extractions of teeth grown in "normal" areas of the mouth? If not, what would be different? I found this on [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/guide/pulling-a-tooth-tooth-extraction), but it only refers to *impacted* teeth:

  > If the tooth is impacted, the dentist will cut away gum and bone tissue that cover the tooth and then, using forceps, grasp the tooth and gently rock it back and forth to loosen it from the jaw bone and ligaments that hold it in place.
- How much time would it take for the space in my palate to recover? Would I expect there to be any long-term "scarring" or similar side-effects, or would the tissue be able to grow back smoothly?

Comment: Teeth impacted in the palate of your mouth are far from the regular tooth impaction and hence, they are referred to as '*maxillary* impacted [name of tooth]'. A simple search and you will find all of the answers to your question. I too had a maxillary impacted tooth however, it was moved rather than removed via a cosmetic procedure. The tissue grows back entirely smooth, much smoother than the surrounding tissue! p.s. it hurts rather alot and a liquid diet will be required to avoid complication in the work up to the extraction site becoming fully healed.

Comment: Nobody but the person doing the procedure can answer this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I had the teeth in question removed.

The dentist's assistant told me that the extractions would more or less be the same as those done on teeth with a more normal placement. The dentist told me that there was some chance of having to cut into the tissue if the teeth were too difficult to remove.

The actual procedure was very straightforward: I was given an anaesthetic, which rendered everything afterwards painless, and the dentist then extracted the tooth. The dentist used something that looked like a knife on one occasion. I was told to avoid drinking, smoking, and hot foods, but did not have to make any major changes to my diet. The little pain there was was also very manageable.